What user-defined function signatures are expected to have a specific purpose?
The C++ language defines swappable as

Any lvalue or rvalue of this type can be swapped with any lvalue or rvalue of some other type, using unqualified function call swap() in the context where both std::swap and the user-defined swap()s are visible.

also

Many standard library functions (for example, many algorithms) expect their arguments to satisfy Swappable

This means that if I write a function and happen to name it swap( Foobar&, Foobar& ) its existence alone could affect the behavior of calls to the standard library, such as std::sort.
The standard library is expecting my own function to perform a specific task, because of its unqualified signature.
Are there any other user-defined function signatures that are expected by the standard to perform some specific task?

begin and end functions can make your class useable in a range based for loop accidently.

"Is there a list..?" List type questions are not good for this site

You're still essentially asking for a list. Just removing the explicit use of "list" doesn't make the question any different.

operator ==, <.

@Jarod42 I love that.  Totally valid.

@Alan Can you point to an official document that says it's wrong for SO? Random opinion from main Meta from 13 years ago is not very convincing, and neither [help/on-topic] nor [help/dont-ask] doesn't forbid questions about list of something.

noexcept move constructor (to avoid to use copy constructor by some container).

Again high rep users misusing the site. The question needs more focus and too broad. Also this is no different than asking for off-site resources/link/recommendation.

@Alan: There's a difference between open-ended list questions (which are not suitable for the site), and questions about lists found in the language specification (by nature closed-ended).  This question is of the latter type, and quite answerable.

Issue with listing is that it is hard to answer when we might miss some items. Leading to partial answer.

Your question might even be extended by typedef in class (as is_transparent).

I do apologize for the conflict this question seems to be causing.  Fundamentally, a hypothetical answer to this question seems to be something a C++ programmer should know.  Specifically, named, free functions that carry a behavioral expectation.

fwiw, the meta list answer argues against questions that require a list of different answers. Its understandable that this doesnt fit the format (only one answer can be accepted etc..) Its not about banning any question whose answer would contain a list of things. That would be somewhat silly imho.

C++20 introduces Customization point object which allow to centralize to one entry point the call before the possible dispatch with customization.

The standard specifies that when the following non-member functions are called, their meanings are "established as-if by performing argument-dependent lookup only". That is, if these function (or function template) names are defined in the same namespace as a program-defined type, they may be called by standard library facilities when that type is involved.

swap (the lookup also finds the std::swap overloads)

make_error_code (only if is_error_code_enum is specialized)

make_error_condition (only if is_error_condition_enum is specialized)

submdspan_mapping

strong_order (called by std::strong_order)

weak_order (called by std::weak_order)

partial_order (called by std::partial_order)

iter_move (called by std::ranges::iter_move, and indirectly by many ranges facilities)

iter_move(e) is required to return a value equal to *e (but possibly with a different type and/or value category).


iter_swap (called by std::ranges::iter_swap, and indirectly by many ranges facilities)

iter_swap(e1, e2) is required to exchange the values denoted by e1 and e2.


begin (called by std::ranges::begin, and indirectly by many ranges facilities; also used by range-based for loop)

begin(e) must return an input_or_output_iterator. Otherwise it is not used.


end (called by std::ranges::end, and indirectly by many ranges facilities; also used by range-based for loop)

end(e) must return a type that satisfies sentinel_for<decltype(ranges::begin(e))>. Otherwise it is not used.


rbegin (called by std::ranges::rbegin)

rbegin(e) must return an input_or_output_iterator. Otherwise it is not used.


rend (called by std::ranges::rend)

rend(e) must return a type that satisfies sentinel_for<decltype(ranges::rbegin(e))>. Otherwise it is not used.


size (called by std::ranges::size, and indirectly by many ranges facilities)

size(e) must return an integer-like type. Otherwise it is not used.



In addition, many member functions and operators may be used by the standard library. For example, std::stack expects a container-like type, and std::istream_iterator expects a type that supports operator >>.

imho it would be good if you explain how you collected the list. Not only would it increase credibility, but also the fish vs teach how to catch fish thingy

I presume all the "called by ranges" functions will demand a specific behavior not merely because of their signature, but also because parameters and return types satisfy a series of concepts?
